# array list whose the value is empty when it printed outside of the retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

why my array list whose the value is empty ? when it printed outside of the retrofit, even I already declare public variable `List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();`

I want printed value arraylist outside of the retrofit but not worked. when printed value arraylist inside of the retrofit it's worked.

this is my code

**Hello.java**

```
List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();
apiService.getGetlistuser("getlistuser").enqueue(new Callback<ResponseDaftar>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseDaftar> call, Response<ResponseDaftar> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<GetlistuserItem> getlistuserItemList = response.body().getGetlistuser();
                for (int i = 0; i < getlistuserItemList.size(); i++) {
                    profileList.add(new Profile(
                            getlistuserItemList.get(i).getUserID(),
                            getlistuserItemList.get(i).getNickname()
                    ));
                }

    /* 
      is working
      for (Profile p : profileList){
          Log.i("info", p.getUserid() + '\n' + p.getNickname());
      } 
    */


            }
        }

    });

    // my value is empty
    for (Profile p : profileList){
        Log.i("info", p.getUserid() + '\n' + p.getNickname());
    }
```

**retrofitinterface**

```
@POST("GetListNews.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<ResponseDaftar> getGetlistuser(@Field("TableName") String paramTable);
```

Comment: You print the list outside the callback. How can you be sure the callback was runned before the print?

Comment: @jhamon any solution ? I want access my value outside retrofit

Comment: yes, you should be print or use the list values after callback execute success otherwise we can not confirm that the request is successfully or there is a way to display but no sure that will print the values try to print value after some delay put handle for few second and on finish delay print value might be help @senaa

Answer (score 2):

You have to check data **inside the response method** *(where you commented)* because **loading of response take some time** and **sometimes** next statement **run before** response will **available.**

Comment: any example for check ?

Comment: according to my opinion you have to do your all coding after you get the successful response....... if you get error while requesting then there is no need to look forward for further code.

Comment: it's ok, same here

Answer (score 2):

@Deepanshu is correct. there may be some delay in getting the data from the server.

So, You can add a `listener` that will trigger after your code to print the list has been populated (if your print code will be in another class) or call another method if it is in same class.

A sample code

```
List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();
public void getData(){
    final Listener listener = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataReceived() {
            //print command goes here
        }
    }
    apiService.getGetlistuser("getlistuser").enqueue(new Callback<ResponseDaftar>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseDaftar> call, Response<ResponseDaftar> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<GetlistuserItem> getlistuserItemList = response.body().getGetlistuser();
                for (int i = 0; i < getlistuserItemList.size(); i++) {
                    profileList.add(new Profile(
                            getlistuserItemList.get(i).getUserID(),
                            getlistuserItemList.get(i).getNickname()
                    ));
                }
                printData(); //if it is in same class
                if(listener != null) 
                    listener.onDataReceived(); //if it is going to happen in another class
    /*
      is working
      for (Profile p : profileList){
          Log.i("info", p.getUserid() + '\n' + p.getNickname());
      }
    */


                }
            }

        });

    // my value is empty
    for (Profile p : profileList){
        Log.i("info", p.getUserid() + '\n' + p.getNickname());
    }
}

public void printData(){
    for (Profile p : profileList){
        Log.i("info", p.getUserid() + '\n' + p.getNickname());
    }
}

// this will be going to make in separate file 
interface Listener{
    void onDataReceived();
}
```

Comment: please check my screenshoot link

Comment: Dude, at the bottom of the code, I created my own listener. You can create your own like this in another class or in same class.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the profileList before its populated.